# Wave equation with Robin and Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

What are the periodic solutions of the following problem:

- Governing equation (wave equation):

  $u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} = 0 $, $\forall x\in[0;L]$, $\forall t\geq 0$
- Robin boundary conditions at $x=0$:

  $u_x(0,t) = k u(0,t)$, $\forall t\geq 0$
- Neumann boundary conditions at $x=L$:

  $u_x(L,t)=0$, $\forall t\geq 0$

where $k$ is a constant and $c=\sqrt{E/\rho}$.

Comment: @Harry49 No, I haven't tried. I can only think about the eigenfunctions (linear normal modes) to be the only periodic solutions. Do you have any idea of any other type of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us search for a solution writing as monochromatic periodic plane waves under the form $u = (A \text{e}^{\text{i}\kappa x} + B \text{e}^{-\text{i}\kappa x})\, \text{e}^{\text{i}\omega t}$. Injecting this *Ansatz* in the wave equation gives the dispersion relation $\kappa = \omega/c$, where $\kappa$ is the wave number. Now, the combination of both boundary conditions gives the linear system
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{i}\kappa - k & -\text{i}\kappa - k \\
\text{i}\kappa\, \text{e}^{\text{i}\kappa L} & -\text{i}\kappa\, \text{e}^{-\text{i}\kappa L}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A \\
B
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0
\end{array}
\right] .
$$
This system has non-trivial solutions $A\neq 0$, $B\neq 0$ provided that its determinant vanishes, i.e.
$$
\kappa L\tan\kappa L = kL \, ,
$$
which solutions in terms of $\kappa = 2\pi f/c$ provide the resonance frequencies. The non-trivial solutions of the linear system give the normal mode shapes $A \text{e}^{\text{i}\kappa x} + B \text{e}^{-\text{i}\kappa x}$, where the wave number satisfies $\kappa L\tan\kappa L = kL$.